# Proving the function $g$, defined by an integral, is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, holomorphic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

> Is the function $g$ (defined towards the end of this question) holomorphic?

Let $h:\partial B_1(0)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. We see that $f:B_1(0)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$f(re^{i\varphi}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1+re^{i(\varphi-\theta)}}{1-re^{i(\varphi-\theta)}}h(e^{i\theta})\mathrm{d}\theta$$
is holomorphic, because
\begin{align}
f(re^{i\varphi}) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i\theta}+re^{i\varphi}}{e^{i\theta}-re^{i\varphi}}h(e^{i\theta})\mathrm{d}\theta\\
f(z) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i\theta}+z}{e^{i\theta}-z}h(e^{i\theta})\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i\theta}h(e^{i\theta})}{e^{i\theta}-z}\mathrm{d}\theta + \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{zh(e^{i\theta})}{e^{i\theta}-z}\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial B_1(0)}\frac{h(w)}{w-z}\mathrm{d}w + \frac{z}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial B_1(0)}\frac{\frac{h(w)}{w}}{w-z}\mathrm{d}w\\
\end{align}

Thus $f(z) = s(z) + zt(z)$ where $s, t$ are holomorphic, so $f$ is holomorphic.

I have come across a question asking me to prove that $u:B_1(0)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$u(re^{i\varphi}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1-r^2}{|e^{i\theta} - re^{i\varphi}|}h(e^{i\theta})\mathrm{d}\theta$$
is harmonic. My approach was to attempt to re-write it as the real part of a holomorphic function, similar to what we have above. However, we see that the denominator of the Poisson Kernel look-alike does not have a "square". If it was squared, the function $u$ would be precisely the real part of the function $f$ I have described above.

Instead, because the denominator is not squared, we have $u = \Re(g)$ where $g$ is defined by

$$g(re^{i\varphi}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1+re^{i(\varphi-\theta)}}{1-re^{i(\varphi-\theta)}}h(e^{i\theta})|e^{i\theta}-re^{i\varphi}|\mathrm{d}\theta$$

I've played around with it, but I can't find a way of showing that $g$ is holomorphic. (I don't even know if it is, because anything involving complex norms often isn't holomorphic.) Is $g$ holomorphic? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: With the change of variable $s=  e^{i \theta}, d\theta = \frac{ds}{is}$ you get $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|s|=1}\frac{1+z /s}{1-z/s}h(s)\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{is}$.
 Using Riemann sums to approximate the integral then $f$ is the locally uniform limit of a sequence of holomorphic functions.

Comment: @reuns The question is not whether $f$ is holomorphic, but whether $g$ is.

Comment: The point is that everything converges locally uniformly and the integrand is real analytic, thus so is the integral, and all we need is to check if the integrand is harmonic or holomorphic. With  $z= r e^{i \varphi}$ then $g(z) = \int_a^b \psi_t(z)dt$ so we care of $\psi_t$ being real analytic, harmonic or holomorphic in $z$. Here the continuity of $h$ tell us the integral and all its derivatives converge locally uniformly on $|z| < 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*tl;dr the question had a typo.*

---

The function $u:B_1(0)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$u(re^{i\varphi}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1-r^2}{|e^{i\theta} - re^{i\varphi}|}h(e^{i\theta})\mathrm{d}\theta$$

Is **not** generally harmonic, and so the corresponding function $g:B_1(0)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by

$$g(re^{i\varphi}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1+re^{i(\varphi-\theta)}}{1-re^{i(\varphi-\theta)}}h(e^{i\theta})|e^{i\theta}-re^{i\varphi}|\mathrm{d}\theta$$

is not generally holomorphic.

*Proof*

Let $h:\partial B_1(0)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. We know that the Dirichlet problem on the unit ball has a unique solution, given by

$$\hat u(re^{i\varphi}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1-r^2}{|e^{i\theta} - re^{i\varphi}|^2}h(e^{i\theta})\mathrm{d}\theta$$

However, using the fact that $\lim_{r\nearrow 1}\frac{1-r^2}{|e^{i\theta} - re^{i\varphi}|} = 0$, we can use elementary inequalities to show that $\overline u(x):= \cases{u(x),\ x\in B_1(0)\\ h(x),\ x\in \partial B_1(0)}$ is continuous on the closed ball, and it clearly agrees with $h$ on the ball. Hence if $u$ is harmonic on the ball, it must be equal to $\hat u$ using uniqueness of the solution to the dirichlet problem.

Now by simply setting $h$ to be a constant function, we see that the two integrals do not agree, so $u$ is not harmonic. It follows that $g$ is not holomorphic (although the harmonicity of $u$ was the property of interest).